# How to code so that when users click on the arrow, the paragraph hide and unhide?

Tags: javascript, html

OK, see this html code

```
<p>This is question.</p>
<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" width="42">
<p hidden>This answer.</p>
```

I want that when user clicks on the image it will remove the `hidden` of `<p>` & show the question.

***How to achieve that with minimum amount of code?***

Comment: You forgot to post your js code.

Comment: Search after "sliding div" on google or here on stackoverflow

Comment: did you try anything at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure javascript way without using jQuery:

```
<p>This is question.</p>
<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" width="42" id="showHideImg">
<p id="showHide">This answer.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("showHideImg").addEventListener("click",function(){
    if (document.getElementById("showHide").style.display=="none")
    {
      document.getElementById("showHide").style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
      document.getElementById("showHide").style.display="none";
    }
},false)
</script>
```

Comment: Great, but can I ask you this? let say if we have many "*<p id='showHide1'>*", "*<p id='showHide2'>*", "*<p id='showHide3'>*", then how can you modify your code?

Comment: Are each of those showHide1, showHide2 triggered by the same image or do you want different images to trigger different showHide? like showHideImg1 triggerring showHide1 and showHideImg2 triggering showHide2?

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.question img').click(function() {
  $(this).next('p').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.hiddenContent {
  display: none;
}

.question img {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="question" id="question-123">
<h3>This is question?</h3>
<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" width="42" class="showContentBtn">
<p class="hiddenContent">This answer.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a JSFiddle. I'm sure you could probably shrink it down more, but here is a start: https://jsfiddle.net/bsq32pds/.. I would suggest that if the answers are supposed to be hidden, you write that every-time you click the image it makes an AJAX call to a server to pull back the answer. This would keep people from inspecting the page, and seeing the answers in the HTML code.

Good luck!!

```
<!--html-->
<p>This is question.</p>
<img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/qTB/5yd/qTB5ydpzc.gif.gif" alt="show answer" height="42" width="42">
<p id="firstQ" class="hidden">This answer.</p>


//JS Code
//start on page load
$(function(){

//on image click
$("img").on( "click", function() {

//remove the class hidden
$("#firstQ").removeClass("hidden");
});
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery & make it easy,
There is a toggle method in jquery, bind event & toggle(hide & show) elements
for example see demo at http://api.jquery.com/toggle/